# Enoent error when trying to create React App

Tags: npm, create-react-app, enoent

I'm trying to create react-app but I'm having a ENOENT problem, this is what the command prompt shows:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:186
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Pedro Fernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  spawnargs: [
    '/d',
    '/s',
    '/c',
    '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
  ]
}
```

Does anyone had this problem and was able to fix it?

Before anyone asks:
These are my system variables path

[Windows System Variables Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkygX.png)

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and using ALL CAPS will not help you get an answer more quickly. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT for attention.

Comment: There is a similar problem reported on the `create-react-app` repo and there is a popular solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908#issuecomment-495064048). Check it out.

Comment: I've done this solution (Adding %SystemRoot%\system32 to my system variable path) and it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

I had the same issue although I checked that link out and it worked so far what I would recommend what they say here as I quote:

"If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version."

```
Step 1:  npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app

Step 2: npm install create-react-app
```

This worked for me hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following inside your terminal:

```
First remove all node_modules: rm -fr node_modules/

followed by:

npm install npm@latest -g

npm install -g create-react-app

npm init react-app my-app
```

Comment: Same problem ENOENT

Answer (score 0):

Try to change react-scripts version to 2.1.8. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've come across this issue a few times.  Usually it's solved by restarting the computer.

Comment: If you have to do it over and over again, then it is not really solved, is it?

Comment: Once in a blue moon I have to restart.  Usually only after I've had it running for days and have started and stopped numerous processes in the mean time.  Yes, you can do things like use netstat to try to get to the exact process that's causing the problem, but I've never found anything to work faster or better than a simple restart.  As evidenced by all of the rest of the non-answers I see lying around.  If this doesn't work, the OP is always welcome to tell me what happened and I'm glad to try to improve this answer.